# win10 pro 64 bit + python 3.6.0 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, image-recognition, cudnn

I was running Tensorflow command in anaconda with python 3.6 and it's giving me an error **ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
Though, I have installed tensorflow-gpu with conda command and checked the packages , but i am not able to figure out the problem.
Below are the list of packages and their version :

```
 **Name                     Version                BuildChanel**
a) Conda                     4.5.12                 py36_0
b) cudnn                     7.1.4                  cudn9.0_0
c) keras-applications        1.0.6                  py36_0
d) keras-preprocessing       1.0.5                  py36_0
e) protobuf                  3.6.1                  py36h33f27b4_0
f) tensorboard               1.12.2           py36h33f27b4_0
g) tensorflow                1.12.0          gpu_py36ha5f9131_0
h) tensorflow-base           1.12.0          gpu_py36h6e53903_0
i) tensorflow-gpu            1.12.0               h0d30ee6_0
```

Please help and advise what is going wrong

[image]

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors mentions this error and links to two issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512 and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

Comment: Please put the error output in the post as text/code instead of a screenshot. This could help people searching for the error find your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check your CUDA and cudnn version.I refer to the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794).

I also met the problem you said, but I installed the following to fix it.

```
cuda 9.0 
tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0
cudnn 7.4.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, 
 I am able to resolve the issue with below commands

import sys

sys.path.append("C:\Users\1010141\Desktop\model\models-master\research\")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\1010141\Desktop\model\\models-master\research\object_detection\utils")

I believe I was working on different directory and later set the directory where model is been kept.